# Not able to insert records via Http.post request in Angular

Tags: angular, http-post, spring-batch

I am trying to understand how to call Http.post method in Angular. I am trying to build a form with certain input fields. As soon as the user would hit the submit button on the UI, it will call a services ( written in springboot) to insert records into a database. Though my springboot services is running fine but I am not able to call it properly from Angular.

**services.ts:**

```
 export class MFinService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

  public addRecord(networth : any){
    return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/networth" , networth);

  }
}
```

**component.ts :**

```
export class NetworthHomeComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor(private mFinService : MFinService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // Reactive cardForm
  cardForm = new FormGroup({
      account : new FormControl(),
      ppf : new FormControl(),
      nps : new FormControl(),
      pf : new FormControl(),
      stocks : new FormControl(),
      mf : new FormControl(),
      online : new FormControl()
  });

  public submitForm(){
    console.log(this.cardForm.value);

    this.mFinService.addRecord(this.cardForm.value).subscribe(
      (data : any) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**Springboot controller class :**

```
@PostMapping("/networth")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addNetworth(@RequestBody Networth networth){
        int result = mFServices.addNetDetails(networth);
        if(result > 0){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("A new records has been inserted !");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**Springboot DTO class :**

[image]

Error :

[image]

**inserted records in database :**

[image]

**Request and Response from the Network tab :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: the name of the object being send the one in database don't seem to match, are both of them have same name in `@RequestBody Networth networth`? eg account in angular vs account_amount in database

Comment: The status is 200 OK, so the error is probably related with the response, that can't be parsed to JSON. Check the network tab and see what the response actually is.

Comment: Added screenshots for the same. Is it happening because the response is in the String format whereas Angular is expecting in the json format ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is not in the http call, but in the form itself.

Try these 2 things:

**IMPORTANT**: Declare/Initialize every field with the proper type to match the expected input DTO for the back (to match the atributes of your 'Networth' back interface)

1. Initialize form:

```
cardForm = new FormGroup({
      account : new FormControl(''),
      ppf : new FormControl(''),
      nps : new FormControl(''),
      pf : new FormControl(''),
      stocks : new FormControl(''),
      mf : new FormControl(''),
      online : new FormControl('')
  });
```

If it still not working, try this:

2. Make yourself a form "mock", something like:

```
// Use the same types that you have indicated on the back!!!
interface CardForm {
      account : string;
      ppf : string;
      nps : string;
      pf : string;
      stocks: string;
      mf: string;
      online: string;
};

constructor(private mFinService : MFinService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

cardForm: CardForm = {
      account : '';
      ppf : '';
      nps : '';
      pf : '';
      stocks : '';
      mf: '';
      online: '';
};

  public submitForm(){

    this.mFinService.addRecord(cardForm).subscribe(
      (data : any) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

If that last way works, then you will know the problem wasn't in your api call.

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue was occurring because my spring boot service was response in the String format. I modified the response to make it in the JSON format :

```
@PostMapping("/networth")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addNetworth(@RequestBody Networth networth){
        int result = mFServices.addNetDetails(networth);
        if(result > 0){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("{\"response\" : \"a new record has been inserted successfully !\"}");
        }

        return null;
    }
```